# How can I continue to use Windows on a laptop when its memory has gone bad?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, memory, memtest

I have low-budget Asus laptop that has some bad memory (confirmed with memtest) - unfortunately the memory is soldered to the motherboard and is not practically replaceable.

I'm able to boot into Windows 8.1, but after a few minutes Windows will crash.

Is there any hope or use for such a computer?

Comment: Salvage parts from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue using an obscure Windows command that allows you to force Windows not to use certain memory addresses. 
Here's what I did
1. Run memtest from a bootable USB. I selected every test except for the hammer test. Also I set the CPU settings in memtest to run in parallel (probably doesn't matter, but made the test run faster). Allow memtest to complete all passes. 
2. Make a note of the highest and lowest memory error addresses reported by memtest at the end of the test. (In my case the lowest was 0x6424c238 and the highest was 0x6F236258).
3. Boot Windows
4. Open a command prompt (run as administrator) and run the following command
`bcdedit /set {badmemory} badmemorylist 0x6`

You will need to replace 0x6 with a value you obtained from your high/low values in memtest. I used 0x6 so all memory addresses that start with 0x6 will be ignored - this was the easiest thing to do since all my bad memory had addresses that started with 0x6. You can append additional memory addresses, separated by spaces (e.g. 0x6 0x7 0x8) at the end of the command if you need them. If your bad memory is in a more narrow range than this example, you can make the address more precise (e.g. 0x6424). 
5. Tell Windows to avoid the bad memory
`bcdedit /set badmemoryaccess no`

Hopefully this information will help save a computer or two for someone.

Comment: A great answer. Lets hope that the OP can boot in order to make these changes. +1

Comment: @Hennes OP answered his own question. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Memtest86 always reports the same addresses as bad, the following may work.  I've never tried it.

Run Memtest86 and note the lowest address it returns as bad.  Use a hexadecimal-to-decimal calculator to convert the address to decimal, then divide it by 1048576.  Subtract 1 from this value.

Bring up the Windows Boot Menu by pressing Space or F8 during boot.  When here, press F10, and you will enter a screen where you can enter boot parameters.  Enter `/MAXMEM=X` where X is the value you found out above.  (You may also want to try the `burnmemory` and `removememory` switches as described [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/12628-windows-7-boot-parameters-editable.html).)

Basically this will tell Windows not to use memory above this address and while you will have reduced RAM it may still work.

However, if your system's memory is defective, it could be the start of other hardware defects that may manifest themselves later.  So unless a known event happened to a specific component on your motherboard's computer, I would not trust this system, but you may find it works reliably after testing.

Comment: So with this method, the higher the memory address of the bad RAM, the better? I will have to run memtest again and notate the specific addresses.

Answer (score -1):

I have replace permanent memory, it is all up to your skill with a solder iron. You could try an usb flash drive configured to be used as RAM.:

Rename your thumb drive as "RAM DRIVE" or something similar, so you can see which drive is being used as RAM.
Delete all the stuff on the flash drive. Check for hidden files.
Right click on My Computer, and go to Properties. Once there, click on Advanced and go to the system output's Settings.
Click on Advanced, and then Edit.
Click on your thumb drive above, and select "user-defined size." Here you can see the size of your flash drive.
Calculate the size of the flash drive, and subtract 5 Mb.
Type this number in the first box. In the second box, type in the same number.
Click Set and confirm all your settings, applying them wherever you can.
Restart your computer.

Comment: flash is not RAM.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-memory-storage-device-speed-computer#1TC=windows-7